# How to use Select for a specific nested list level

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would like to parse every sublist of a nested list and select only those elements that have a certain length, i.e., smaller than 10 elements while maintaining the list structure. Is there any quick trick that makes it work ?

```
Matrix = {
 {
  {
   {O1,2,22,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,28,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,28,14,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,21,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,1,21,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,27,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,22,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,28,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,23,27,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,9,10,26,24,28,18,17,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,9,10,26,24,28,16,15,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,7,8,26,24,28,20,19,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,7,8,26,24,28,18,PoP2,17,27,13,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,7,8,26,24,28,18,17,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,7,8,26,24,28,16,15,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,5,PoP1,6,24,28,18,PoP2,17,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,2,1,21,22,24,26,12,11,25,23,27,17,PoP2,18,28,14,13,D1},
   {O1,2,1,21,22,24,26,10,9,25,23,27,17,PoP2,18,28,14,13,D1},
   {O1,2,1,21,22,24,26,8,7,25,23,27,17,PoP2,18,28,14,13,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,11,12,26,24,28,18,PoP2,17,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,9,10,26,24,28,18,PoP2,17,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,21,23,25,7,8,26,24,28,18,PoP2,17,27,13,14,D1}
  }
 }
}
```

the result needs to be :

```
{
 {
  {
   {O1,2,22,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,28,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,28,14,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,22,21,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,2,1,21,23,27,13,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,27,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,23,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,21,22,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,1,2,22,24,28,14,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,28,27,13,14,D1},
   {O1,2,22,24,23,27,28,14,D1}
  }
 }
}
```

Appreciated any help,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map[Select[Length[#] < 10 &], Matrix, {2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would again use `DeleteCases` just like in my answer to your last question [Filtering nested lists while maintaining the list level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184485/45431):

```
DeleteCases[Matrix, s_List?(Length[#]>=10&), {-2}]
```

> {{{{O1, 2, 22, 24, 28, 14, D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 23, 27, 13, D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 24, 
>       28, 27, 13, D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 24, 28, 14, 13, D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 24, 23, 27, 
>       13, D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 21, 23, 27, 13, D1}, {O1, 2, 1, 21, 23, 27, 13, 
>       D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 23, 27, 28, 14, D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 23, 27, 13, 14, 
>       D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 23, 24, 28, 14, D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 22, 24, 28, 14, 
>       D1}, {O1, 1, 2, 22, 24, 28, 14, D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 24, 28, 27, 13, 14, 
>       D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 24, 23, 27, 28, 14, D1}}}}

Comment: Not sure why, but applying this does not work correctly. Whereas, the answer given by Mr. Schumacher works. Thanks anyway.